# Is it true that $\kappa\to[\kappa]^2_2$ iff $\kappa\to[\kappa]^2_\kappa$ for inaccessible $\kappa$?

Tags: set-theory, large-cardinals

Recall that the *square partition relation* $\kappa\to[\lambda]^k_\eta$ holds iff for every $f:[\kappa]^k\to\eta$ there exists $H\in[\kappa]^\lambda$ such that $f"[H]^k\neq\eta$. I.e. said in words, everytime we colour the $k$-element subsets of $\kappa$ in $\eta$ many colours, we can find a subset $H\subseteq\kappa$ of size $\lambda$ such that we omit a colour when colouring $k$-element subsets of $H$.

Note that for $\kappa>\omega$, $\kappa\to[\kappa]^2_2$ holds iff $\kappa$ is weakly compact, and it's not too hard to see that $\kappa\to[\kappa]^2_2$ implies $\kappa\to[\kappa]^2_\kappa$. Furthermore, it's a result of Rinot ('14) that every regular uncountable cardinal $\kappa$ satisfying $\kappa\to[\kappa]^2_\kappa$ is threadable, which by a result of Todorcevic ('87) implies that such a cardinal is weakly compact in $L$, making the two notions equiconsistent. This leads me to my question.

> **Question.** Can we separate inaccessible cardinals $\kappa$ satisfying $\kappa\to[\kappa]^2_\kappa$ from the weakly compacts? By this I mean showing that $\textsf{ZFC}+\exists\text{weakly compact}$ can't prove that every inaccessible $\kappa$ satisfying $\kappa\to[\kappa]^2_\kappa$ is weakly compact.

The standard way to do this is to use Kunen's method of starting with a weakly compact cardinal, adding a $\kappa$-Souslin tree to kill the weak compactness, resurrect the weak compactness in a further forcing extension and show that $\kappa$ has the desired property in the intermediate extension. But the presence of such a tree either makes $\kappa$ singular or implies that $\kappa\not\to[\kappa]^2_\kappa$ (this is mentioned on slide 12 of [Rinot's ESTC '17 talk](http://papers.assafrinot.com/rinot_budapest2017a.pdf)), so that doesn't work in this case.

**EDIT:** This edit is based on the comments below. Replaced Todorcevic' result that regular uncountable cardinals $\kappa$ satisfying $\kappa\to[\kappa]_\kappa^2$ reflects stationary sets to Rinot's result that such cardinals are threadable. Both are true, but we need threadability to show the equiconsistency.

Comment: This is related to Question 8.5 in Shelah's "On what I do not understand (and have something to say) Part I" [Sh:666], where he asks specifically if $\lambda\nrightarrow [\lambda]^2_\lambda$ holds for the least $\omega$-Mahlo cardinal.    If $\lambda$ is (weakly) inaccessible not $\omega$-Mahlo, then you get some strong colorings of pairs, but this is buried in Chapter 4 of Cardinal Arithmetic and pretty hairy...

Comment: This is problem 16 in the problem list of Erdos and Hajnal: Unsolved problems in set theory http://www.renyi.mta.hu/~p_erdos/1971-28.pdf. I started writing up a paper on those problems, will be happy to send it to you when finished.

Comment: @Dan 1. Which result of Jensen? 2. Does inaccessible="strongly inaccessible"?

Comment: @saf 1. I was thinking of the result that every regular cardinal reflecting stationary sets is weakly compact in $L$. I believe it's due to Jensen, but correct me if I'm wrong. 2. Yes

Comment: @saf (1) is Theorem 6.1 in Jensen's paper on fine structure of L.

Comment: https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF02764953

Comment: @saf Hmm, now I'm a bit confused, as it seems like Jensen states right above Theorem 6.1 of his paper that regular stationarily reflecting cardinals are weakly compact in L. But giving the theorem a second look it seems like what he's showing is that, in L, every regular threadable cardinal is weakly compact - is he assuming that, in L, every regular stationarily reflecting cardinal is threadable?

Comment: @ToddEisworth Ah right, thanks. Yeah as far as I can see, he proves in his book that every inaccessible $\lambda$ such that $\lambda\to[\lambda]^2_\lambda$ is $\omega$-Mahlo. But yes, showing that his question can consistently be refuted would answer my question affirmatively.

Comment: @PéterKomjáth I wasn't aware that this is one of those 'big' open problems! I'd love to get a copy of that paper, thank you.

Comment: @Dan What Jensen shows in that paper is that if $V=L$ then a regular uncountable cardinal $\kappa$ is weakly compact iff $\square(\kappa)$ fails iff there exists no $\kappa$-Aronszajn tree iff there exists no $\kappa$-Souslin tree iff $\kappa\rightarrow[\kappa]^2_\kappa$ holds iff every stationary subset of $\kappa$ reflects.

Comment: @saf Ah, so this shows that being regular, uncountable and stationarily reflecting isn't downwards absolute to L, right? As then Jensen's result would contradict Shelah-Mekler's?

Comment: @Dan Right. That's why we needed http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=3271280

Comment: @saf Yeah I see, thanks for that - I've edited it now to reflect this.